# Scaling tensor approximation by symmetric tensor decomposition with SciPy's L-BFGS-B

Tags: optimization, scipy, tensor, scaling, tensor-decomposition

I am trying to approximate a symmetric tensor of which the values are in the range of [1e-7,1e-4], by a symmetric tensor decomposition of lower rank. For this I am using the L-BFGS-B method in SciPy's optimization package.

The relative errors (based on the Frobenius norm) I am obtaining are quite big (greater than 1). After some research I have come to the conclusion that there is need for scaling, as my tensor is 'poorly scaled'. When I multiply all values of X with 1e7, I do obtain a smaller relative error (in the range of [1e-4,1e-3]), but only when the modes of X have a small dimension in comparison with the chosen rank of the symmetric tensor decomposition.

Since I am not that familiar with the concept of scaling in numerical optimization, is there a better way to solve this scaling problem, so that I can obtain a small relative error even when the dimension of the modes of X is large in comparison with the chosen rank?

I am also doing some research about the existence of a low rank approximation, as this may not even exist. While this may be the case, reproducing the first experiment of [Sherman & Kolda](https://arxiv.org/abs/1911.03813) (2020), does not give me the same order of magnitude of the relative errors. This means that there should exist some improvements to be made to my implementation, of which I think only the scaling aspect can be improved.